# Why Java Singleton needs to prevent the reflection attack

Tags: java, reflection, singleton

*Effective Java 2nd* describes the **Enum Implementation** as the best practice to implement a Singleton in Java.

But the advantage of that implementation against the **Static Holder Implementation** is that the `enum` can prevent the reflection attack.

So, there comes the question: Why do we need to prevent the reflection attack of singleton?

The other implementations of Java Singleton are just resolving the issues of **multiple threads** and **lazy initialization**.

These problems will and often appear at the daily development, but the reflection attack seems more like a **Security Issue**.

If the attacker can hack and crack your program, he and she could do whatever he and she wants, it seems it is no need to break the Singleton.

Comment: Reflection isn't always used for an "attack." The enum singleton is used to guard against legitimate uses of reflection breaking your code.

Comment: @4castle Could you post a example of it? I still don't understand how to  "legitimate uses of reflection breaking the singleton". If you want to not affected by serialization, just don't implement that interface. Use the reflection with a singleton seems really rare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Honestly, this line of thinking is an absolute overkill. Almost anything can be achieved with reflection (until Java 9, at least) and I've never seen a library (JVM's own libs included) that protects against reflective manipulation, because that's the job of `SecurityManager`. If someone wants to defeat the singleton by reflection - you should probably let them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Wafer Li, in theory reflection could create a second instance of a non-`enum` singleton, and so could deserialization. These are not "attacks" but ways that client code could defeat singletonness. The whole *point* of API writing is to guarantee documented behavior. If one leaves such a huge hole in the guarantee, why bother writing a singleton at all?

Also, lazy initialization of singletons is useless. Pointless. Static holder is redundant and just a whole bunch of code.

So why resist simple, elegant, fully-implemented, standard, best-practice `enum` for singletons?

Why?

Comment: I am not resist the `enum` for singleton. I do think the `enum` is more elegant than the static holder. I am just curious about why border the "reflection attack". It now turns out to prevent the problem of deserialization. Thanks.